# How to detect only GitHub merged branch event with Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, github, jenkins-pipeline

I need some help to understand some basic and advanced concepts.

I configured a webhook on GitHub to send the event and created a job "GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling" on Jenkins. I can detect each commit/push... But I only want to run a pipeline when a "Branch A" merged to "Branch B". Do you know how to do this ? Thank you.